# An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and managedObjectContext ios6

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios6

I know other people have already posted having the same issue, but I cannot get any of the answers to solve my issue. I'm getting the following error:

```
An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and managedObjectContext
```

I have included in my appdelegate.m:

```
WorkoutExercisesTVC *workoutExercisesTVC;
workoutExercisesTVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
workoutExercisesTVC.fetchedResultsController = self.fetchedResultsController;
```

I have in my table view controller class:

```
#import "WorkoutExercisesTVC.h"

@implementation WorkoutExercisesTVC

@synthesize fetchedResultsController = __fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;

- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{   
    // 1 - Decide what Entity you want
    NSString *entityName = @"WorkoutExercise"; // Put your entity name here
    NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

    // 2 - Request that Entity
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

    // 3 - Filter it if you want
    //request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"enity.name = Blah"];

    // 4 - Sort it if you want
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order"
                                                                                 ascending:YES
                                                                                  selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

    // 5 - Fetch it
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                    managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
    [self performFetch];
}
```

My error occurs in the setupFetchedResultsController method in step 5 (Fetch it).

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me get self.managedObjectContext so it is no longer null. Let me know what ever other information you may need! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you follow the lazy instantiation pattern familiar from the apple samples?

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController {
   if (_fetchedResultsController) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
   }

   // set your fetch request, entity, predicate, sort descriptors etc. 

   NSFetchedResultsController *aController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
                initWithFetchRequest:request 
                managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                cacheName:nil];

   NSError *error;
   aController.delegate = self; 

   [aController performFetch:&error]
   _fetchedResultsController = aController;

   return aController;
}
```

And when you need to refresh your table view (should not be necessary if you implement the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods):

```
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Finally, set a breakpoint and check if the managed object context is nil or not - maybe you did not retrieve it correctly from your delegate.